# php trim not trimming the spaces

Tags: php, trim

I am trying to trim everything except the actual word so i have this wordpress function

```
the_author_meta('author_image', $_GET['author']);
```

which should return in this format

```
test@test.com
```

but its returning like this

```
                                                        ken@flashreport.org-38.jpg
```

with tons of spaces and i tried this

```
<?php print trim($matching_image, "\n"); exit; ?>
```

and

```
<?php print trim($matching_image); exit; ?>
```

and both seem to still have the spaces in the html

here is my entire function

```
<?php $matching_image = the_author_meta('author_image', $_GET['author']); ?>
<?php print trim($matching_image, "\n"); exit; ?>
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">  
<?php if (is_numeric($matching_image)){  ?>
<img src="/wp-content/authors/missing.jpg" alt="<?php the_author(); ?>" title="<?php the_author(); ?>" />
<?php }else{ ?>
 <img src="/wp-content/authors/<?php print $matching_image; ?>" alt="<?php the_author(); ?>" title="<?php the_author(); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the spaces are coming from a failed `trim()`? Add some extra characters like `print "~" . trim($matching_image, "\n") . "~"` to make sure it's not coming from elsewhere.

Comment: are you sure those are spaces?  any way they could be something like &nbsp; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will this help?

```
$matching_image = preg_replace("/^(\\s)*|(\\s)*$/","$2",$matching_image);
```

or this one

```
$matching_image = preg_replace("/^(\\s)*\|(\\s)*$/","$2",$matching_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that you are probably dealing with NON-BREAKING SPACES. Try this, it worked perfectly for me:

`trim($matching_image, chr(160)); // 160 is ASCII code for non-breaking space`